# SSH failed with "no error"

Tags: ssh, firewall, google-cloud-platform

I've create a Google Compute Engine VM instance and I'm trying to SSH into it. Strangely, the SSH command fails with "No error" and exits.

Why might this be happening? Maybe it's a corporate Firewall issue? If so, how can I find out? I'm running Cygwin on Windows 2008 server, and the Google VM isntance is Debian Linux.

```
J@VAPMAP01001 /cygdrive/c/Users/J
$ ssh -o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null -o CheckHostIP=no -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -    i /home/J23587/.ssh/google_compute_engine -A -p 22 J23587@107.178.220.0 --

ssh: connect to host 107.178.220.0 port 22: No error

J@VAPMAP01001 /cygdrive/c/Users/J
```

Comment: This site is for programming questions. We are not general software/network tech support.

Comment: Perhaps not, but it's a problem many people may face, so worth asking and answering.

Comment: doesn't matter. My car's passenger door seal is leaking. Maybe I'll go ask for advice on a medical forum. It's ok - other people have the same problem...

Comment: The "no error" error message is apparently some kind of cygwin bug. See [here](https://cygwin.com/ml/cygwin/2014-06/msg00005.html) for discussion of the same behavior with a different program.

Answer (score 2):

There seems to be a bug in cygwin that causes this. When I got this error, all I had to do was exit cygwin, open cygwin, and try again. Worked fine.